# define more parameters in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on rails defines 7 parameters in the controller,

If I want more parameters, can I add variables to the controller, or should I create a new controller?

If I have to create another controller, I tried to defined it by:

**created controllers/taskseachperson_controller.rb that contains:**

```
class TaskseachpersonController < ApplicationController

def index

    end
end
```

**helpers/taskseachperson.rb contains:**

```
module TaskseachpersonHelper
end
```

**views/taskseachperson/index.html.erb contains:**

```
<h1>Listing tasks</h1>

<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>num of tasks</th>
      <th>num tasks left</th>
   </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

**config/locales/routes.rb file contains:**

```
Todo::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :tasks
    root to: "tasks#index"

    resources :taskseachperson
    root to: "taskseachperson#index"
end
```

but, when I try to connect to: localhost:3000/taskseachperson

I got this error:

```
NoMethodError in TaskseachpersonController#index

undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: /home/alon/projects/todo

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

If I have to create another controller, what is my problem?

**UPDATE:**

**I have a file: models/person.rb:**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :done, :name, :task
end
```

Comment: By parameters you means actions like index, edit, show, etc ...?

Comment: Provide your routes file..

Comment: no, I have these parameter. I want to define: persons_page (for example)

Comment: I have a page that produces me the workers and the number of tasks for each of them.
what I want is to put a link near each name: "show tasks", and if I press it, I will be directed to a page that shows me all the tasks of the worker X..

Comment: You have `Person` and `Task` models?  Did you use a generator script for the `Tasksearchperson` controller/view?  Why are the names not pluralized?

Comment: @bdares, I update the topic (added models/person.rb)
I didn't use the generator script for Taskseachperson.
and is it important to define the name pluralized? I have a page that produces me the workers and the number of tasks for each of them. what I want is to put a link near each name: "show tasks", and if I press it, I will be directed to a page that shows me all the tasks of the worker X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure some of those files don't actually contain what you claim (like `person.rb` containing `class Task` or the route file containing a `root to:`).  But here's what appears this appears to be:

A Person `has_many :tasks`.

A Task `belongs_to :person`.

Both `Person` and `Task` were generated as scaffolds, so they work fine.  Now, you want to list tasks that belong to a person, and you're not sure whether it should be handled by the `PersonsController` or the `TasksController`, so you just went ahead and made a new controller just for that.

This appears to be a case for nested routing:

```
resources :persons do
  resources :tasks
end
```

Then you could just access `/persons/4/tasks` to see what tasks belong to a person.

As for why your code doesn't work, you didn't actually post the trace, or even the line number, so it's very difficult to diagnose from here.